# Trying to grep multiple strings with multiple files

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Have to grep customerName with multiple strings in one file.
and only custromer name in another file

For Example:

```
stdbuf -oL -eL  docker-compose up 
| grep --line-buffered -E 'CustomerName|Address' >> Logs1.txt | grep --line-buffered -E 'CustomerName' >> Logs2.txt
```

i tired with above commands not working

Comment: What is your question? What's the input format? What output do you get and how is that different to what you expect?

Comment: what is your input? a file? a piped/stream of data on stdin? is there a reason for using `--line-buffered`?  define `not working` ... syntax error? no output? wrong output? command hangs? something else?  please update the question with these additional details

Comment: Form docker logs, trying greps logs 
stdbuf -oL -eL  docker-compose up grep --line-buffered -E 'CustomerName|Address' >> Logs1.txt | grep --line-buffered -E 'CustomerName' >> Logs2.txt

Comment: so, `docker-compose up` is generating the data you with to run `grep` against? if 'yes', please update the question with the output from `docker-compose up`

Comment: yes ...from docker logs only first conditon is working:
 grep --line-buffered -E 'CustomerName|Address' >> Logs1.txt.
Second condition not working : grep --line-buffered -E 'CustomerName' >> Logs2.txt

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- output from `docker-compose up` is to be piped to the `grep` calls
- the intention is to run `docker-compose up` once but run 2 sets of `grep` calls
- results of `grep` calls are to be *appended* to the output files (`Logs1.txt` and `Logs2.txt`)

One idea using `tee`:

```
docker-compose up | grep -E 'CustomerName|Address' | tee -a Logs1.txt | grep -E 'CustomerName' >> Logs2.txt
```

**NOTES:**

- `tee -a` says to `a`ppend to `Logs1.txt`; to overwrite `Logs1.txt` remove the `-a`
- `tee [-a]` also copies its stdin to stdout which in this case is piped to the 2nd `grep` call
- this particular use of `tee` works because the 2nd `grep` call is a subset of the 1st `grep` call

---

Alternative use of `tee` where we wish to copy the entire set of `docker-compose up` output so we can run 2 completely distinct `grep` calls:

```
docker-compose up | tee >(grep -E 'Address' >> Logs1.txt) | grep -E 'CustomerName' >> Logs2.txt
```